# Apache returns 200 status for non existing page

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Apache returns 200 status for non existing page. 
For example we have `example.com`. If we'll type a weird url after that it will return 404 `example.com/asdmifas` , BUT if we will go to existent page `example.com/page.php` and add that weird part after backslash it will return status code 200 and rendered `/page.php`.

Here is my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L] 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: by "and add that weird part after backslash" do you mean pointing to `example.com/page.php/whateverrandomstring` ?

Comment: @JavierLarroulet yes, exactly!

Comment: Weird. It's been a long time since I moved all my stuff to Nginx, so my Apache is very rusty, but I don't recall having that problem. Can you check your Apache's `access.log` and `error.log` and see what happens when you access that URL? It may well be that your config is considering everything after `index.php` as a query string parameter (some PHP frameworks and CMS' do just that)

Comment: @JavierLarroulet there is no rule which would rewrite to `index.php` or `page.php`. could only imagine a custom `404` page which wrongfully sends a `HTTP 200` header. this just cannot be determined by the snippet posted, which does not seem to cover the actual problem. it could also be the global configuration.

Comment: Actually, I browsed to some third party sites from companies I know who use Apache+PHP and could replicate the behaviour on those sites. Looks odd, but it doesn't seem to be completely out of the ordinary.

Comment: @JavierLarroulet I`m not using any CMS or framework. error.log and access.log shows nothing valuable